# Replacing data sources for C# in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, datasource

I'm working on a group project with a class mate He sent over the file and I worked on my portion. But when I attempted to run the code it wouldn't start. My partner informed me that I had to specifies the mdf file's location in my pc. Once I made those corrections I still couldn't get it to run. I had to replace the Data Source as well but when I attempted to do so I still couldn't  get the code to run. Maybe I don't know how to properly replace the data source. The error code I'm receiving is this

Error code:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)'

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Savion\source\repos\Education\Education.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Student", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text (using code formatting), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; C) are difficult to read clearly by visual impaired user and many more reasons. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

The error is asking you to install SQL Server Express LocalDb, which is the database engine specified in the connection string.  See [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15)